# Copy a Range From One Worksheet To The Last Row of Data On Another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a range of cells in column "B" and paste it after the last row of data on an another sheet in the same workbook in the same column. I have the following code but I can't figure out how to actually paste the data.

```
Dim lastRow As String

Sheet9.Range("B2:B100").Select
Sheet9.Range(Selection,Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy


lastRow = Sheet14.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheet14.Range("B" & lastRow).Activate
Sheet14.Paste
```

Comment: Do you want copying form B2 to last cell in B:B column? From B2 to the first empty cell? Anyhow, no need of any selection...

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code line, please:

```
Sheet9.Range("B2:B" & Sheet9.Range("B100").End(xlDown).Row).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheet14.Range("B" & Sheet14.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
```

It copies form B2 to the last empty row, after B100...

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Range

- To learn why the 1st code is not recommended, read through the following 'classic': [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).
- The 2nd code shows how to copy a range in three steps: define `CopyRange`, define `PasteCell`(`PasteRange`) and finally `Copy/Paste`.
- To better understand the 2nd code, check out [Range.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) and [Range.PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) from Microsoft, [this tutorial](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/cut-copy-paste-with-macro/) or [these videos](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/).
- To make the codes work in your case, replace `Sheet1` with `Sheet9`, `Sheet2` with `Sheet14` and `B10` with `B100`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPasteSelectActivate()
    
    ' A quick fix, not recommended. It's a poorly improved version of what
    ' the macro recorder what produce.
    ' Rather use one of the 3 ways below.
    
    Dim LastRow As Long ' In this case 'As String' works, too.
    
    Sheet1.Activate
    Sheet1.Range("B2:B10").Select
    Sheet1.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheet2.Activate
    Sheet2.Range("B" & LastRow).Activate
    Sheet2.Paste

End Sub

Sub CopyPaste3Ways()
    
' Define CopyRange.
    
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    
    ' Either...
    'Set CopyRange = Sheet1.Range("B2", Sheet1.Range("B2:B10").End(xlDown))
    ' ...or (I prefer the following 'xlUp' approach):
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set CopyRange = Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
    
    Debug.Print "CopyRange:", Sheet1.Name, CopyRange.Address
    
' Define PasteCell.
    
    Dim FirstEmptyRow As Long
    FirstEmptyRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Dim PasteCell As Range
    Set PasteCell = Sheet2.Range("B" & FirstEmptyRow)
    
    Debug.Print "PasteCell:", Sheet2.Name, PasteCell.Address
    
' The CopyPaste
    
    ' 1st Version
    ' This version is the most efficient of these 3 versions, but it can
    ' only be used for copying values (not formulas, formats... etc.).
    
    ' Either...
    'PasteCell.Resize(CopyRange.Rows.Count, CopyRange.Columns.Count).Value _
      = CopyRange.Value
    
    ' ...or:
    ' To better understand it, you can define a 'PasteRange'.
    Dim PasteRange As Range
    Set PasteRange = PasteCell.Resize(CopyRange.Rows.Count, _
                                      CopyRange.Columns.Count)
    PasteRange.Value = CopyRange.Value
    Debug.Print "PasteRange:", Sheet2.Name, PasteRange.Address
    
'    ' 2nd Version
'    ' This version will copy 'everything', including formulas, formats etc.

'    ' The following line...
'    CopyRange.Copy PasteCell

'    ' is just short for:
'    CopyRange.Copy Destination:=PasteCell

'    ' 3rd Version
'    ' This version will do the same as the previous, but as a downside,
'    ' it will change the selection on the 'PasteSheet' to 'PasteRange' and
'    ' will set the 'CutCopyMode' to 'xlCopy'. But as an upside, you can
'    ' choose what you want to copy by 'adding arguments' to 'PasteSpecial'.
'    ' Put the cursor right behind 'PasteSpecial' and press 'SPACE' to
'    ' see the various arguments and their parameters.

'    CopyRange.Copy
'    PasteCell.PasteSpecial
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```